# Change default font type/size in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, default, font-face, font-size

How do you change the default font type and font size in TinyMCE?

I'm using the advanced skin and I've changed the `body, td, pre` style in default/content.css but it still doesn't change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there are several **content.css** and only one is used to style your editor depending on your **configuration settings**.

You should use the **content_css** configuration option and name an own css file where you can overwrite the editors defaults (the **content.css** you were recently looking for). In your **init function** use something like

```
content_css: "http://localhost/css/my_tiny_styles.css",
```

and in `my_tiny_styles.css` or whatever file you choose you use

```
font-family: myfont1, myfont2, sans-serif;
```

Comment: Can i add direct font family in as `font-family:Segoe Ui` in tinymc editor intialise

Comment: @Eldho: you would have to specifiy font-familiy in the css-file you set using content_css

Comment: I set font in css but still it not working  `body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
}`  and i set content css as `content_css: '/Design/style/layout.css'` still not working

Comment: does the font exist and is it accessible from the tinymce iframe?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to resolve this problem.

By adding your own custom styles into our CSS file by defining tinymce id.

```
#tinymce .mceContentBody p {
   font-family: your_font_name !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the default of the dropboxes rather than the display css only, with tinyMCE 4 it is now:

```
setup : function(ed) {
 ed.on('init', function(ed) {
  ed.target.editorCommands.execCommand("fontName", false, "Calibri");
  ed.target.editorCommands.execCommand("fontSize", false, "11pt");
 });
}
```

EDIT:
this is the setup option of the init function as explained here:
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup

Comment: this fails to tell us where this code should be added.

Answer (score 0):

For people having troubles adding a stylesheet because of path troubles or whatever reason, this should do it pretty simple:

```
setup : function(ed) {
     ed.on('init', function(){
         $(this.getDoc()).find('head').append('<style>p{margin:0;}</style>');
     });
}
```

**Note I used jQuery, but can of course be done without it as well.**

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to do it without touching CSS or any other codes.

1. Use the plugin 'TinyMCE Advanced'
2. Activate it in settings.

More detailed instructions [here](http://www.theaaronloy.com/enable-font-size-menu-in-tinymce-wordpress-easy/).

Comment: This plugin is about TinyMCE for Wordpress. The OP is about the TinyMCE control itself ;)