# Tiny mcE set font family and font size in toolbar

Tags: php, jquery, html, tinymce

I Want to set the default fontfamily and font size to 'Calibri' and '11px'.
I try to using this code

```
        //set the editor font size
        ed.on('init', function()
        {

            this.getBody().style.fontSize = '11pt';
            this.getBody().style.fontFamily = 'Calibri';



        });
```

It is working well, The text font is 'Calibri' and font size is '11px' . But the font family  and font size on the tool bar 'font family' and 'font sizes'.
I try with jquery in focus event . But it is not working.

```
$('#mceu_0-open span').text(tinymce.editors[0].getBody().style.fontFamily);
$('#mceu_1-open span').text(tinymce.editors[0].getBody().style.fontSize);
```

I  want to set the text of the font family is 'Calibri' and size is '11px'.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to add fontsizeselect to your toolbar config param:

toolbar: "sizeselect | bold italic | fontselect |  fontsizeselect",

Update

tinymce.init({
  fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt"
});

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('.tinymce').tinymce({
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
            ed.execCommand("fontName", false, "Calibri");
            ed.execCommand("fontSize", false, "11");
        });
    }
});
```

[Changing the default font family in TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924141/changing-the-default-font-family-in-tinymce)

Comment: It work only when load the editor, When start typing the font family and font size are reset to "Font family" and "Font size".