# Tinymce: How can I display the default font family or the font size on initialize?

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce-4

Is there any way to display the default font family or the default font size on my button?
Currently the button is shown as:

[image]

Schriftart = Font Family,
Schriftgröße = Font Size

The default values are "Microsoft Sans Serif" and "10px" and now I want to display this values after the initialization of my editor.
Like this:

[image]

Is this possible?
Or is the font family only displayed when I select them?

Comment: hey felix did you find any solution for this? i was able to select the font by default but not reflect that in the dropdown, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[Check out this site](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:content_css), this page shows you how to change the editor's default font size and font dropdown.

Comment: Sorry but I have no code for this problem! :/ I want to know how I can set the default values before I set a content or click any button.

Comment: I changed my answer. please refresh!

Comment: Sorry this isn't that what I need. I Know how change the default value but I dont know how I can display them on my button. Here an example:
If I use the "removeFormat"-Funktion I cant see the default font family value. The user should see what the default font is.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand the question.

Comment: Ok! When you start the editor, you cant see the default value, because they dont appear. The buttons show the standard value "Font Family" (in german "Schriftart"). But I dont know the default value. And I want to display the default values and not "Font Family".

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924141/changing-the-default-font-family-in-tinymce)

Comment: you tagged the question  **tinymce-4**

Comment: Yeah I know. And the solution in this post don't work with tinymce 4.

Comment: Ohh sorry I am so stupid! I have not seen the second post. So you can set the default values, but it does not still appear in the Button. :/