# Select a font in TinyMCE fontselect

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have defined a font select object in TinyMCE like so:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  
  toolbar: 'fontselect'
});
```

The problem is that when the editor is started, the font selected is "Times New Roman" and I need it to be "Arial". How can this be changed? Is it a keyword in `tinymce.init` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: 'textarea',  
   toolbar: 'fontselect',
   setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
        ed.execCommand("fontName", false, "Arial");
        //Or ed.target.editorCommands.execCommand("fontName", false, "Arial");
        ed.execCommand("fontSize", false, "12");
    });
}
});
```

Try with above code and check . please go through: [Changing the default font family in TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924141/changing-the-default-font-family-in-tinymce)

Comment: thanks for the link, I used the answer for TinyMCE v4.3.6., that's the one that worked.

Comment: Indeed the other answer works for latest versions, for which ed.onInit is no longer defined.

Comment: Also only `ed.on('init', function (ed) {...}` worked for me