# TinyMCE default font list

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using two initializations for TinyMCE:

- Default font list. Just AS IS.
- Custom font list, which also contains default font list plus custom fonts. The problem is that using the lines (2 and 3):

  `tinyMCE.init({
      selector: '#htmleditor',
      content_css: ['https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi'],
      font_formats: 'GugiQuiter=Gugi;',
      });`

It just deletes the default font list and shows the only font listed.

Any ideas of which is the default font list for this editor?

Kind regards,

Comment: It seems to be "Verdana", according to this topic, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924141/changing-the-default-font-family-in-tinymce (maybe you'll find it interesting).

Comment: @TakitIsy Thanks but I need the full font list so the second initialization has all the default fonts plus added custom fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, list found finally:

```
tinyMCE.init({
...
theme_advanced_fonts : "Andale Mono=andale mono,times;"+
    "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
    "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;"+
    "Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;"+
    "Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;"+
    "Courier New=courier new,courier;"+
    "Georgia=georgia,palatino;"+
    "Helvetica=helvetica;"+
    "Impact=impact,chicago;"+
    "Symbol=symbol;"+
    "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
    "Terminal=terminal,monaco;"+
    "Times New Roman=times new roman,times;"+
    "Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;"+
    "Verdana=verdana,geneva;"+
    "Webdings=webdings;"+
    "Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats",
...
```

});